# Equating functions: does f=g?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$f(x)=\frac{x^2-2x}{x-2}$

$g(x)=x$

Does $f=g$?

I said yes but my homework said they aren't equal.

Comment: Well, $f$ is not defined at $x=2$.

Comment: The function $f$ is not defined at $x=2$. The function $g$ **is** defined at $x=2$. A bit of a trick question, since although it is not precisely true, it is generally considered "acceptable" to write $\frac{x^2-2x}{x-2}=x$.

Answer (score 6):

$$ f(x)=\begin{cases} \text{undefined} \quad \text{at} \quad x=2 \\x \quad \text{otherwise}\end{cases} \quad .$$

$g(x)=x$ (for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$), so $f \neq g.$

Note that $\frac{x^2-2x}{x-2} \equiv \require{cancel}\frac{x\cancel{(x-2)}}{\cancel{x-2}} \equiv x \quad$ **only if** $\quad x-2 \neq 0 \iff x \neq 2.$

Answer (score 2):

Well although they can algebraically be shown to be the same, the domains aren't the same. $f(x)$ has a "hole" at $x=2$ because it's not defined at that point because of the denominator becoming zero. However that's not the case with $g(x)$, therefore they're not exactly the same.

Another good example of this is $f(x)=\sqrt{x(x-2)}$ and $g(x)=\sqrt{x} \sqrt{x-2}$. They have different domains thus they look different when graphed and aren't equal, although they are algebraically equal.

Comment: As pointed out by alexqwx, they're algebraically equal under certain conditions (such as $x \neq 2$)